# Calculating Covariance and correlation of a target variable with all columns in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, covariance, correlation

I have tried fixing the weird bug I am getting time and again while calculating covariance and correlation of all variables(one by one) of a data frame with the target variable , but I get the following error :-

```
> for(i in 1:290)
+ {
+     ins_comb<-subset(InsTrainNumer,!(is.na(InsTrainNumer[,i])))
+     print(nrow(ins_comb))
+     variable<-as.matrix(ins_comb[,i])
+     target<-as.matrix(ins_comb$target)
+     ins_cor[i]<-cor(variable,target = NULL,use="everything")
+     ins_cov[i]<-cov(variable,target = NULL,use="everything")
+     print(ins_cor[i])
+     print(ins_cov[i])
+ } [1] 452061  Show Traceback
```

Rerun with Debug

```
 Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

Where lies the catch ?

Comment: Error in cor(variable, target, use = "everything") : 
  supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'

Comment: I get the above error when I remove the = NULL and cast them as.vector .

Comment: Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL' 
5 array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x), 
    NULL) else NULL) 
4 as.matrix.default(target) 
3 as.matrix(target) 
2 is.data.frame(y) 
1 cor(as.matrix(variable), as.matrix(target))

Comment: Please help, don't know how to get around this error !

Comment: At last, recovered, figured out ! i need to cast x' as.matrix

Comment: Don't comment on your own question. If any of those comments are important, edit them into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your strategy of going one by one is pretty inefficient. Just use `cor` and `cov` on the whole dataframe (or a subset thereof):

```
> set.seed(1)
> d <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), ncol = 5))
> cor(d)
           V1          V2         V3         V4          V5
V1  1.0000000 -0.21752487  0.2976402 -0.1523604 -0.37085773
V2 -0.2175249  1.00000000 -0.2839989  0.1778480 -0.06401162
V3  0.2976402 -0.28399885  1.0000000  0.2180834  0.13805728
V4 -0.1523604  0.17784796  0.2180834  1.0000000 -0.27922504
V5 -0.3708577 -0.06401162  0.1380573 -0.2792250  1.00000000
> cov(d)
           V1          V2         V3         V4          V5
V1  0.8340324 -0.17310141  0.2200998 -0.1461380 -0.30846352
V2 -0.1731014  0.75927736 -0.2003796  0.1627604 -0.05080004
V3  0.2200998 -0.20037960  0.6556520  0.1854637  0.10181248
V4 -0.1461380  0.16276039  0.1854637  1.1030602 -0.26709083
V5 -0.3084635 -0.05080004  0.1018125 -0.2670908  0.82948786
```

You can then extract out whatever portion of those correlation/covariance matrices you actually want.